# nested For loop doesnt seem to be working properly

Tags: python

My forloops here are not incrementing properly. any list that I go through using the variable p, doesn't seem to want to increment. It keeps using and outputing the same value even though it should be going through the list and I dont know how to go about fixing it.

```
for p in range(0,len(C13Masses)):
        for l in range(0,len(sortedMass)):
            newError = ((float(C13Masses[p])-float(sortedMass[l]))/float(C13Masses[p]))
            exp_ratio = float(AbuList[l])/float(Abu)
            #print newError

            if -error <= newError <= error and Tratio[p]*(0.01) <= exp_ratio <= Tratio[p]*(2.9):
                Hits.append(sortedMass[l])
                print newError, Tratio[p]*(0.01), exp_ratio, Tratio[p]*(2.9), ' ', C13Masses[p]
```

Here is a section of the output:

```
these are the 13C Masses:  [247.22498116056002, 248.22833599836002, 
249.23169083616, 250.23504567396003, 251.23840051176]
0.00189079878665 0.000168240943605 9.35616976571e-06 1.99758297649e-38
0.198593689562 0.00189079878665 0.377861498675 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.133748786249 0.00189079878665 0.537307237955 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.121834092247 0.00189079878665 0.358098400434 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.121601834165 0.00189079878665 0.32636250439 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0893994654456 0.00189079878665 0.497940678778 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0893985351189 0.00189079878665 0.413524472399 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0893824364222 0.00189079878665 0.324574566585 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0893816274425 0.00189079878665 0.435714057661 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0893376189448 0.00189079878665 0.32438300182 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0892978171418 0.00189079878665 0.368315187893 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0892961991823 0.00189079878665 0.326617924076 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0892508154191 0.00189079878665 0.424667156221 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.089003024926 0.00189079878665 0.439130295968 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0851244929285 0.00189079878665 0.532198844226 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0693502375046 0.00189079878665 0.335078701191 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0529637866655 0.00189079878665 0.378723540117 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0286653522119 0.00189079878665 0.327320328214 0.548331648129   247.224981161
0.0122736430045 0.00189079878665 0.433670700169 0.548331648129   247.224981161
-0.00372801662321 0.00189079878665 0.451805497909 0.548331648129   247.224981161
```

as you can see the last second third and last columns all dont change but they should

so it works: it's just printing out the values that held true in the if statement. Im just dumb

Comment: All the columns you mention only depend on `p`, not on `l`. Hence, the values do not change inside the inner loop. If you let it run long enough, you should see changes as `p` is incremented.

Comment: May I see `print(len(sortedMass))`